# Object lifecycle management and IoC containers

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm updating a game from single player to multiplayer. In this case the game was originally written with most classes being single instanced. e.g. there was a single Player object, a single GameState object, etc. That is, each of these objects lived as long as the application.

Now that more than one player can play at once I obviously need to support creating more than one Player object, GameState object, etc. Over the course of working on this I have come to realize that most objects have one of three lifespans:

1. App's lifespan, e.g. a Conductor to handle navigation
2. Player's lifespan, e.g. the SettingsViewModel for the current player
3. Game's lifespan, e.g. the GameState for the current game

I'm curious how others deal with the creation of these different objects using an IoC container. I want to avoid creating factory classes for each class with a player or game lifespan.

Comment: Configuring the lifestyle / lifetime is typically something most DI containers support. Which platform and DI framework are you talking about?

Comment: I'm aware that some containers have support for lifetime management to an extent, but imagine a class which takes a IPlayer as a parameter (as many classes do in this case). If there is a single container then how will you register this class without requiring a factory for the runtime data? I've experimented with creating separate containers for each lifecycle, but am still struggling to connect the various pieces when concerns cut across lifespans.

Comment: In this case .NET/C# however I'm actually interested in how people solve this design problem more generally. In particular, I don't want to rely too much on a given container as it may not be available on every platform I target.

Comment: Although admirable, the possibilities of different platforms differ pretty much. For instance, languages on the end of the static-dynamic spectrum (such as C++ and PHP) don't have a type system that is as rich as those of .NET and Java. This limit the possibilities of DI containers a lot. In the current state, DI containers on the Java side seem to be based completely on XML based configuration, which is quite insane, since big XML files will create a maintenance nightmare. I think .NET has the best DI containers which give the best opportunities to create maintainable software.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "If there is a single container then how will you register this class without requiring a factory for the runtime data?" .

Comment: @Steven: please update your information regarding IoC containers outside .NET. First of all there are a lot of IoC containers in Java that use annotations before 2012 and PHP can be more rigid then you think. Use === instead of == when comparing values.

Comment: You also might add the request - response lifespan and the turn based life span. All those life spans are application specific. With regards to IoC is the question how do the caller and callee relate to one another? Is the callee performing a function which is restricted to the call of the caller or not? Is the callee performing a function which requires a lot of CPU or not? The life span of business objects is conceptually unrelated to the life span of objects in an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/gridmaster/IOC-with-Ninject) is an example of IOC that may help. The project is called IOC-with-Ninject. It uses Ninject plus an IOC container class to manage all object life spans. You will need to do a little [research on Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/learn.html) to customize it to your specific needs, but this is your IOC container solution (IMHO) if you are using .NET and will help you organize your code base. This is a personal choice, but I swear by it. If you are not using .NET it will still give you an easy pattern to follow. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Many IoC containers have custom life-cycle scopes which you can manage as your wish. For example in Ninject you can define your custom life cycle scope as follows:

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<Service>().InScope((c, o) => yourCustomeScope);
```

As long as the yourCustomeScope variable has not changed, one single instance of the Service object is returned each time the kernel receives a request for IService. As soon as the yourCustomeScope variable changes, a new instance of Service will be created on the next request for IService. yourCustomeScope can be the current player instance, the game object or anything that you want to change the lifetime of the Service object, based on its reference change.

However, the objects that you just mentioned are more likely to be entities rather than services for which I don't think injection is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the factories approach works the best.

Controlling lifespan of instance is clunky for support and requires efforts, knowledge of all of the classes lifespan requirements and dependencies, time for configuration and management of the configuration. In same time the use of factories is natural and code specific.

Factories (implementation) creation might be avoided by using [proxy factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) . You can also have factories returning generic arguments to further decrease the needs of factories (interfaces) creation.

If still too many factories are required I suggest reviewing the code flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is in part a rehash of some of the comments of the previous answers but I have tried to exemplify expand a little on some of the reasoning.

Once you get into the domain of managing injected objects lifespan, you probably should be creating factories for these objects.

The underlying problem is that the composition root is not aware of what the environmental context of the call will be that needs to create the object.

I think I should take a step back and explain at this point.

Received wisdom on dependancy injection is to have a composition root some where near the entry point of the code. There are many good reasons for this that are not difficult to find on the web so I won't go into that here.

The composition root is where you map your interfaces (usually, but possibly objects) to their implmentations. You can pass in information that is available at this point to the constructor. So you can pass in a reference to an object whose lifetime is current at the time of execution of the composition root.

However, if the lifetime of the composition root does not overlap with the life time of the object you want to create you have to defer the execution of the constructor until the object needs to be created. This is why you need to have a factory. You can pass a factory method in to your mapping at this point and thus pass in the information needed to generate the object, but allow the creation to happen at the time it is required not when the composition root is executed.

You do not need a factory class to do this factory methods are fine, moreover the factory method can be inlined and so the code overhead is not much more than if we were creating the objects in the composition route.

If we have a project with 2 services where the first service is dependant on the first and we only want the lifetime of the second service to start when we create the first service we might have something like the following. (I am using ninject to give a code example, but I expect that other IOC containers work similarly in this respect.)

```cs
`   
    public class Service1:IService
    {
        private Func<IService>serviceFactoryMethod _Service2Factory;
        public Service1(Func<IService>service2FactoryMethod)
        {
            _Service2Factory=service2FactoryMethod;
        }

        public void DoSomethingUsingService2()
        {
            var service2=_Service2Factory();
            service2.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public void CompositionRoot()
        {
            var kernel= new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind.ToMethod(m=>
            { 
               return new Service1(m.Kernel.Get<IService2>());
            }
        }
    }

`
```

This example does not address how you would manage the lifetime of the App, players and games lifespans, but hopefully it gives sufficient clues as to how to remove lifetime issues related to dependancy injection.

Side note: that using Ninject you would be able to change the scope of Service2 in order to manage its lifetime to go beoynd the lifetime of Service1. For example, if you knew each instance of a game were to happen on its own thread (OK, this maybe somewhat unlikely), you might use InThreadScope for the game.